How can I go back to the home page in flutter web view while invoking a cloud function?
I am invoking a cloud function (created from stripe extension) to generate a url. The function block in flutter for invoking the cloud function is as follows:
  createPortalLink() async {
    emit(StripePaymentPortalInitial());
    try {
      HttpsCallable callable =
          FirebaseFunctions.instanceFor(region: 'europe-west3')
              .httpsCallable('ext-firestore-stripe-payments-createPortalLink');

      final result = await callable.call({
        'returnUrl': 'https://google.com',
        'locale': 'auto',
      });

      emit(StripePaymentPortalSuccess(result.data['url']));
    } on FirebaseFunctionsException catch (e) {
      emit(StripePaymentPortalError(e.toString()));
      debugPrint('Customerportallink function error:');
      debugPrint(e.toString());
    }
  }
}

Here the function works and I set the returnUrl to google.com. But I want to return to the home page in my app (flutter web) on return. I have used Uri.base instead and it gives me an error. What is the alternative? How can I fix this?
